# How Columns_update() Function Works in Trigger To Find Updated Columns Name

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012, trigger

I am in confuse about trigger function **Columns_Update()**. 
 i Have Basic Idea about this function that it returns a **varbinary** and it is use to get **updated Columns** in Trigger
 even i have Find The code to get updated Columns Name But  have still confusion in Bit Representation.I would be very Thank Full if Some one Explain Me this Function or Give Reference

I got Following Function

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.GenColUpdated
(@Col INT, @ColTotal INT)
RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN;


DECLARE
@ColByte INT,
@ColTotalByte INT,
@ColBit INT;
-- Calculate Byte Positions
SET @ColTotalByte = 1 + ((@ColTotal-1) /8);
SET @ColByte = 1 + ((@Col-1)/8);
SET @ColBit = @Col - ((@ColByte-1) * 8);
RETURN Power(2, @ColBit + ((@ColTotalByte-@ColByte) * 8)-1);
END;
```

and Use same Function in trigger Like this

```
set @ColUpdatedTemp=dbo.GenColUpdated(@ColCounter,@ColTotal) ;

If COLUMNS_UPDATED()& dbo.GenColUpdated(@ColCounter,@ColTotal) =@ColUpdatedTemp
```

I didn't understand this Condition

```
dbo.GenColUpdated(@ColCounter,@ColTotal) =
        @ColUpdatedTemp
```

it doesn't make Any sense to me .First you are assign the value and than Check it

Comment: Please do not post the same question in multiple stackexchange sites http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31199367/how-columns-update-function-works-in-trigger-to-find-updated-columns-name. please wait for your question to be answered and if you are not satisfied with the quality of answer, you can look at posting the same question again at the other site.